# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>) at Object.error (<anonymous>:96:30)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, json

Necesito de su ayuda por favor, tengo un problema al retorno de un `exception`.
En el `json $.parseJSON(response.responseText)` recibe un `html` que da error:

```
error: function (response) {
       var errors = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
       simple_alert('', errors, 'warning');    
}
```

El error esta cuando retorna en `throw new \Exception($this->message());`

> Log: [2019-04-25 11:02:54] local.ERROR: exception 'Exception' with
>   message 'No es posible asignar el estado no vigente al servicio
>   Adaptaciones Funcionales De La Vivienda, ya que posee 0 persona(s) en
>   estado activo, 
>               63 persona(s) en estado derivado, 
>               0 persona(s) en estado suspendido' in C:\wamp64\www\SNAC_DES\01.

Código:

> PHP\app\Http\Utilities\ServiciosPrestaciones\ValidacionPersonasDependientes.php:62
>   Stack trace:
>   0 C:\wamp64\www\SNAC_DES\01. Codigo PHP\app\Http\Utilities\ServiciosPrestaciones\ValidacionesCambioVigenciaServicio.php(40):
>   App\Http\Utilities\ServiciosPrestaciones\ValidacionPersonasDependientes->run()
>   1 C:\wamp64\www\SNAC_DES\01. Codigo PHP\app\Http\Controllers\ServiciosPrestaciones\ServiciosController.php(576):
>   App\Http\Utilities\ServiciosPrestaciones\ValidacionesCambioVigenciaServicio->run()

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente en algún método de tu acceso a Datos esperas por lo menos 1 resultado, y quizá la query está devolviendo empty, en tal caso podrías cachar la excepción y evitar caer en este error, y podrías devolver un elemento vacío en lugar de NULL.

Comment: el throw new \Exception($this->message()); retorna un html y al comenzar con un caracter < al tomarlo en json da el error.

Comment: Es correcto, tendrías que escapar los caracteres especiales con formato HTML.